# Is there any way to know how many degrees of freedom has this discrete equation?

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following discrete equation:

$$d_1 + \dots + d_N = D$$

Where $N$ can be between $1$ and $N_C$. Furthermore, $d_i \geq 0$.

Is there any way to express the set of all solutions as some $\mathcal{Z}^M$ where $\mathcal{Z}$ is a discrete set of $K$ elements for some $M$ and $K$? Here $M$ would the number of degrees of freedom, if one can say such thing exists. Well, I know that enumerating all possible solutions (stars and bars) in $\mathcal{Z}$ and set $M=1$ would do it, but my question is whether there is an $M>1$ for which we can say this.

It seems to me that it is impossible, but I have no idea where to begin with. I don't even know how should I tag this question or if it does make sense at all!

Edit: Of course, I am not asking that you do this for me (unless you find it trivial), but if somebody knows if there has been work done in the same line I would appreciate it!

Second (hopefully last) edit: I am going to write down the other way of approaching it I've thought of. $N,M,D$ change their meaning here, careful:
I have a set $\mathcal{F}\in\{0,1\}^M$ such that $$\mathcal{F} = \{\mathbf{x}|\forall i < M-D , \sum_{j=0}^{D} x_{i+j} \leq 1\}$$

Again the question is if there is a way to express $\mathcal{F}$ in that way. Maybe you'll find it more useful.

This is related to some posts I did in physics and cross validate, but I thought of it as a tangential problem and thought it might be interesting! Again, I am probably wrong and it might as well be worthless...

Comment: Is $1+2+3=6$ the same as $1+2+3+0+0=6$?

Comment: @Henry no it isn't. In one we would consider $d_1 = 1, d_2=2, d_3=3$ and $N=3$, in the other $N=5$. So the set (in the first interpretation) should be the union for all $N<N_C$ of the sequences $(d_1,\dots,d_N)$ that hold that inequality.